# Why don't I find web form with master in visual studio 2022?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am new to ASP.net I try to perform CRUD operations on form. But in visual studio 2022 I can't find web form with master. Web form with master exists in a tutorial which I follow, but when I try there is no such option, there is only web form option.
So, how to solve this problem. I have also downloaded the web development workload

[image]

Comment: please put a reference of your tutorial, Are you learning Asp.net Core 6 ?

Comment: If you've created a **.NET Core** (incl. .NET 5 or .NET 6) solution - webforms is **no longer supported** on those platforms - so it's clear you can't find that item in the menu anymore....

Comment: @Mamink I don't know I am beginner  [here can see](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZLPv5X0DH4&ab_channel=QuickieWiki)
Then what is the alternative of this??

Comment: @ – marc_s Then what is the alternative of this??How to create a form and perform the CRUD operations on it?

Comment: Create a .NET Framework 4.8 solution instead, I guess.

Comment: Have you tried 'Add', then 'New Item'? That shows all available items.

Comment: Given that both "Web Form" and "MVC 5 View Page (Razor)" are both options then it's likely that you're targetting some version of .NET Framework already. What do you see when you try the "New Item..." option?

Comment: If you're new to ASP.NET then you should really be learning ASP.Net Core first. I understand that Web Forms is fairly simple to grasp but it isn't (really) being used anymore for new projects.

Comment: BTW - that video is a horrible way to learn (for me anyway), it goes way too quickly with distracting music and no explanation of what is happening. You see momentarily before they pick the "Web Form with Master Page" option that they initially move the mouse over "New Item..." this is where you can find all the installed templates.

Comment: There's even a comment on the video asking exactly this question and giving the same answer "New Item..."

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so, this assumes you created a asp.net webforms application. While they are older, and consiered somewhat legacy, the learning curve is MUCH MUCH less then using MVC.

And for visual 2022, they added some great new features for web forms. So, you can have cool things like "live" preview of data.

So, for example in place of this for a web form:

[image]

You can now see/get this:

[image]

***So some of the BEST NEW features in vs2022 are for web forms!!!
(so much for them being dead!!!).***

You can read about these exciting new features in vs2022 for web forms here:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/design-your-web-forms-apps-with-web-live-preview-in-visual-studio-2022/

Ok, assuming you did create a new webforms project in vs2022?

this one:

[image]

then this:
[image]

So, now when you say right click on your project, choose add, you should see this:

[image]

then you should see this:

[image]

However, maybe you are opening a existing web form applcation?

If this is the case, then you have to make sure you selected the addtional worflows and options during the install of vs2022. If you missed that, you need to select those options.

Under tools->get tools and features

[image]